# React Admin resource name with path variable

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-admin, authprovider

Is it possible to specify a Resource name in React Admin with a path variable?

**Problem**

When the user authenticate, if admin, should see a list of email accounts. Clicking on the email it redirects to the path `experts/${email}/requests`.

To map this path I need to define a new Resource for each email. The problem of this is that I have to do it before the authentication.

What I would like to have, is a path variable for the resource name. e.g. `experts/:email/requests`.

**Example of the current implementation**

```
function App() {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState<string[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const experts = await firebase.firestore().collection("experts").get();
      const docIds: string[] = experts.docs.map((doc) => doc.id);
      setEmails(docIds);
    })();
  }, []);

    return (
      <Admin
        authProvider={authProvider}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
      >
        {(props) => {
          if (props.admin) {
            return [
              emails.map((email) => {
                return (
                  <Resource
                    key={email}
                    options={{ label: `${email}` }}
                    name={`experts/${email}/requests`}
                    list={RequestList}
                    edit={RequestEdit}
                  />
                );
              }),
              <Resource name={`experts`} list={ExpertList} />,
            ];
          } else {
            return [
              <Resource
                options={{ label: `${props.email}` }}
                name={`experts/${props.email}/requests`}
                list={RequestList}
                edit={RequestEdit}
              />,
            ];
          }
        }}
      </Admin>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a path variable (not possible with React Admin) I decided to override the login of the Firebase authProvider to fetch the data right after the user log in.

*The timeout is needed because it can happen that the localStorage is setup after the first rendering.*

```
let authProvider = FirebaseAuthProvider(firebaseConfig, options);
const login = authProvider.login;
authProvider = {
  ...authProvider,
  login: async (params) => {
    try {
      const user = await login(params);
      const experts = await firebase.firestore().collection("experts").get();
      const docIds: string[] = experts.docs.map((doc) => doc.id);
      localStorage.setItem("emails", JSON.stringify(docIds));
      await timeout(300);
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("error", error);
    }
  },
};
```